# Server KVM via ethernet

Tags: ethernet, kvm

I'm looking for a new KVM box for my server room. I have 3 server connected through a KVM box with PS2 + VGA wires.
I want to move monitor, keyboard and mouse 7mt far from server rack then I would like to know if exists something like a KVM with only USB3 cable and using ethernet protocol. With this I will easily cover the distance with a CAT6 cable. But I don't know if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Google's giving me something close-ish as a first hit ("ethernet KVM switch" was what I used):

switch - [https://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-8-Port-CAT5-Switch-TK-CAT508/dp/B00I3GKLP2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I3GKLP2)
USB cables(same as from the switch page) - [https://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-8-Port-CAT5-Switch-TK-CAT508/dp/B00I3GKJEK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I3GKJEK)

> Manage servers over CAT5 cables for distances up to 30 m
>
> 8 Ethernet ports to connect to servers
>
> Dual Console support Supports both USB and PS/2 connections

There's probably more, and probably something rack-mount to boot, but that's 8 ports already.

Comment: Does it use TCP connection or is just a RJ45 connection for kvm?